# zookeeper client does not provide CLI with "jline support is disabled" message

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, apache-zookeeper, jline

I just brought up `CDH 5.4` and installed zookeeper. I used zkCli successfully many times before. This time the command line launch stops before getting to the prompt with

```
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled
2015-05-04 18:18:33,936 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@975] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-05-04 18:18:33,952 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@852] - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2015-05-04 18:18:33,985 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1235] - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x34d12349d0a15cf, negotiated timeout = 30000

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
```

I know the usual print out is 
JLine support is enabled

Is that what's getting it stuck? I don't see any way to change this one the Cloudera manager config page.

Comment: I reported this bug two months ago: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-758 . Unfortunately, Cloudera has yet to respond.

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: please note answer is from 2015. It is probably not relevant anymore but may serve historical purpose and have some light on similar 'modern' cases.

**SHORT**

Cloudera has broken `zookeeper 3.4.5-cdh5.4.0` in several places. Service is working but CLI is dead. No workaround other than roll back.

**LONG**

Assign a bounty on this ;-). I have stepped on this mine too and was angry enough to find the reason:

Zookeeper checks `JLine` during `ZooKeeperMain.run()`. There is try-catch block which loads number of classes. Any exception during class loading fails whole block and JLine support is reported to be disabled.

But here is why this happens with `CDH 5.4.0`:

1. Current opensource `Zookeeper-3.4.6` works against `jline-0.9.94`. Has no such issue.
2. In `CDH 5.4` Cloudera has applied the following patch:

```
roman@node4:$ diff zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.3.3/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeperMain.java zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.4.0/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeperMain.java

305,306c305,306
<                 Class consoleC = Class.forName("jline.ConsoleReader");
<                 Class completorC =
---
>                 Class consoleC = Class.forName("jline.ConsoleReader");
>                 Class completorC =
316,317c316,317
<                 Method addCompletor = consoleC.getMethod("addCompletor",
<                         Class.forName("jline.Completor"));
---
>                 Method addCompletor = consoleC.getMethod("addCompleter",
>                         Class.forName("jline.console.completer.Completer"));
```

3. CDH 5.4 uses `jline-2.11.jar` for ZooKeeper and it has no `jline.ConsoleReader` class (from `2.11` it is `jline.console.ConsoleReader`).
4. `Jline 0.9.94` in turn has no `jline.console.completer.Completer`.

So there is incompatibility with any existing JLine. Any `Cloudera CDH 5.4` user can run `zookeeper-client` on his/her cluster and find it does not work.

Open source `zookeeper-3.4.6` depends on `jline-0.9.94` which has no such `patches`. Don't know why `Cloudera` engineers have done such a mine.

I see no clean way to fix it with `3.4.5-cdh5.4.0`. I stayed with `3.4.5-cdh5.3.3` dependency where I need CLI and have production clusters.

5. It seemed to me both `jline-0.9.94.jar` and `jline.2.11.jar` in classpath for zookeeper will fix the problem. But just have found Cloudera made another 'fix' in ZK for CDH 5.4.0, they have renamed `org.apache.zookeeper.JLineZNodeCompletor` class to `org.apache.zookeeper.JLineZNodeCompleter`.

But here is the code from `ZooKeeperMain.java`

```
Class<?> completorC =                    Class.forName("org.apache.zookeeper.JLineZNodeCompletor");
```

And of course it meaan practically it is not possible to start ZK CLI in CDH 5.4.0 proper way. Awful work. :-(

Comment: A bit late to the party and not using cloudera but encountered this as well running standalone zookeeper shell to connect to a zookeeper cluster. Added the jline jar from hadoop libs folder to zookeeper/libs/ and the cli worked again.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase  and passe this code :

```
# Add libs to CLASSPATH

    for f in $HBASE_HOME/lib/*.jar; do
      CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$f;
    if [ "$COMMAND" = "zkcli" ] ; then
      CLASSPATH=`echo $CLASSPATH | sed 's/jruby-cloudera-1\.0\.0\.jar//g'`
      CLASS="org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMainServer" ;
    Fi
    done
```

> it works for me :)